# argparse: usage reporting for individual choices of a positional argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to refactor a program to use the new standard argparse module. Given the structure below, should I be using [choices](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#choices) for the primary positional argument, [subcommands](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), or some other method?

```
foo [OPTION]... COMMAND [PACKAGE(S)]...

Commands:
    available -  show packages available to be installed
    install   -  download and install packages, including dependencies
    remove    -  uninstall packages
    ...snip
    version   -  display installed version of package

Options:
    -d,--download          download only
    -i,--ini=FILE          use alternate setup.ini
    ...snip
```

Choices example, concise & clear, but no usage help for each command:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commands = "available install remove ... version".split()
parser.add_argument('command', choices=commands, 
    help="generic help for all 12 commands goes here")
```

Choices is logically more in tune with the program, as what comes after the command on the command line is largely the same for all of them. While subcommands seems to wants me to treat each command one as world mostly to itself and involves 3 times the code. However there doesn't seem to be a method to display usage for each choice in choices(?) Perhaps there's a third route I'm not seeing?

I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with the [sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) option.

You wont necessarily need to code more: build commands classes, each one carrying its own setting (using inheritance where needed), in your `Main` cli class instantiate the main parser and then hand it over to the commands that will care to add/set their own [subparser](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers).

The answer is short, but if it's not clear tell me and I'll add a code sample.

---

#### Rough Example

You should build your commands as classes:

```
class Install(BaseCommand):

    help = "download and install packages"

    @classmethod
    def interface(cls, cmd_parser):
        cmd_parser.add_argument('--foo')
        cmd_parser.set_defaults(cmd=cls)    # this line is very important

    def start(self, foo=None):
        # command execution
```

And your command line interface should be a class too:

```
class Main(BaseCli):

    def __init__(self):
        self.commands = [Install]   # just the command classes

        self._parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        self._subparsers = self._parser.add_subparsers()

    def load_interface(self):
        for cmd in self.commands:
            cmd_parser = self.add_command_parser(help=cmd.help)
            cmd.interface(cmd_parser)

    def add_command_parser(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._subparsers.add_parser(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        return self._parser.parse_args(args, namespace)

    def start_session(self, namespace):
        # this will instantiate the appropriate command class
        cmd = namespace.cmd()
        # and call its start method with the user args
        cmd.start(**namespace.__dict__)
```

To be used like this:

```
cli = Main()
cli.load_interface()
args = cli.parse_args()
cli.start_session(args)
```

Notice that with this approach you'll have all the power of inheritance by your side! :)

Comment: Maybe it's the way I've been going about using sub-commands then? I've got 2 lines for each choice before even getting to the point of reacting to them, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/maphew/source/browse/other/cmdline.py) `def subs()`

Comment: @mattwilkie: It would be kind of you to give a +1 (meaning that you find this answer at least useful) since you're asking me to go through your code. (But I'll take a look anyway...)

Comment: @mattwilkie: You can drop functions and swith to classes, that way it 'll be easier to maintain and implement, I added a code sample.

Comment: Thank you very much Rik. I didn't upvote the initial answer because in that form I couldn't tell if it was helpful or not. I'm just beginning to understand and use classes (and inheritance not at all) and didn't know how to begin implementing the advice. Now I have something to chew on! so thanks again.